# Have there ever been accidents due to a vacuum failure that hasn't been noticed?

Tags: accidents

When the vacuum system fails, the artificial horizon slowly goes back into it's non-vacuumed position. I found no picture on that but it's a quite high angle of bank that is indicated.

Has there ever been an accident because of the failure of the vacuum system? In flightsim, I always needed some time to realize the AH is no more working and adjusted my bank to "fly straight" again.

Comment: On my first cross-country flight during training my vacuum pump failed (VFR) and the first thing I noticed was that the artificial horizon was a little low, but the larger telling sign was that the gyro compass was lagging heavily. A quick look at the vac gauge confirmed and by the time I turned around it was a complete failure. I landed and the school confirmed the pump was bad, but gave me the option to continue, which I declined (the instruments were not required).

Comment: t does not qualify as *vacuum* failure, because airliner IRUs use solid-state (vibrating or laser) gyros, but [this West Atlantic Sweden CRJ2 crashed on Jan 8th 2016](https://avherald.com/h?article=4920a18a/0000) due to attitude indicator failure—and poor design, because the system had enough information to declare itself failed, but didn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There have been many accidents because the vacuum system failed; AOPA has [a good article](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/1999/june/flight-training-magazine/in-flight-emergencies-vacuum-pump-failure) that discusses some of them, and see [this NTSB preliminary report](https://www.ntsb.gov/investigations/_layouts/ntsb.aviation/brief.aspx?ev_id=20160503X70529&key=1) for an example.

As for accidents caused because the pilot didn't notice, that's a more difficult question: if the pilot didn't survive then there's [no definitive way to know what happened](https://www.ntsb.gov/_layouts/ntsb.aviation/brief.aspx?ev_id=20140324X00546&key=1) and what he experienced. It's always possible that the pilot was fully aware that the vacuum system failed, he just wasn't good enough at [partial panel flying](https://www.avweb.com/news/features/Partial-Panel-Peculiarities-223580-1.html) to keep the aircraft under control.